# Httpd Issue for Apache

Tags: redhat, httpd

I am having trouble starting the httpd service I have tried several ways from the internet still result is zero. I have attached the picture of the error. if anyone can help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koR8N.png)

Comment: Do not post images of text. Paste it into the question using the code blocks. The error states that the address is already in use and that it can't bind to the socket. Is there anything else listening on the port that Apache is configured to use?

Comment: Thank You very much I have tried different solutions but forgot this simple one.

Answer (score 0):

It can't bind to the socket you've defined in the Apache config to use. Have you tried looking to see if anything is running on the port with something like `sudo lsof -i :<port_number>`?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the directory /var/log/httpd exists and logs under that directory are accessible by 'apache' user, messages mentioned can't open the logs:
AH00015: Unable to open logs